# Date format: not updating existing record

Tags: php, date, mysqli

I am working on a project where i have to update record on the basis of date, but record is not updating and if i update record without date where clouse its working fine.
I have change format of date becouse the date in mysql table column in different format.

**Ist i changed date format as:**

```
<option
value="<?php $dat1=$q['dt_period_start_date'];
//for example $dat1=2011-04-01;
echo date('d-M-Y',strtotime($dat1));?>&nbsp;to&nbsp;<?php $dat2=$q['dt_period_end_date'];
echo date('d-M-Y',strtotime($dat2));?>">

//now i have date in 01-Apr-2011 to 31-Mar-2012 format
```

**2nd I have to update by this date**

for updating i using this:

```
$qry=mysqli_query($con,"update dbo_tbfeemaster set nu_amount='$amount3' where nu_sub_id='$subscription3' and vc_member_type='$member_type3' and vc_financial_year='$financial_year2' ");
```

and this code is not working and my data not being update.

**3rd If I give date manualy**

If i give static as fetched by the database date in sql query the code is working fine and record get update.  see code:

```
 $qry=mysqli_query($con,"update dbo_tbfeemaster set nu_amount='$amount3' where nu_sub_id='$subscription3' and vc_member_type='$member_type3' and vc_financial_year='01-Apr-2010 to 31-Mar-2011' ");
```

it showing fine...actualy if i use '$financial_year2' in query its not working fine if i use static date as '01-Apr-2010 to 31-Mar-2011' its working fine.....and if i echo $financial_year2 it give same as '01-Apr-2010 to 31-Mar-2011

I have made all possible as i can but unknown by root cause of the problem, let me know what and why my data is not updating and how to resolve it....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a query that works, it is fairly easy to see what is wrong. Just `echo` your queries together. Just make it `echo` instead of `mysqli_query()`.Yup, as simple as that.

```
echo "update dbo_tbfeemaster set nu_amount='$amount3' where nu_sub_id='$subscription3' and vc_member_type='$member_type3' and vc_financial_year='$financial_year2'";
echo "<br>";
echo "update dbo_tbfeemaster set nu_amount='$amount3' where nu_sub_id='$subscription3' and vc_member_type='$member_type3' and vc_financial_year='01-Apr-2010 to 31-Mar-2011' ";
```

and you will see what you have done wrong immediately!

Comment: Sir, it showing fine...actualy if i use '$financial_year2' in query its not working fine if i use static date as '01-Apr-2010 to 31-Mar-2011' its working fine.....and if i echo $financial_year2 it give same as '01-Apr-2010 to 31-Mar-2011.

Comment: I told you to echo your queries, not  $financial_year2

Comment: If both queries are equal and a second one is working, then first one is working too.